Why is ot returning TRUE in first case and FALSE in the second?
I understand 0.3 does not have an accurate binary representation.
Suppose I run the following code:

Why is the answer "True" in the first case and "False" in the second? Shouldn't both be false?

https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf

This question is similar to: Why is there a precision loss for floating-point numbers?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not post images as the main question, which makes it difficult to properly index for the web search engines.

What in the question title is ot? If a mistyped it, I still don't see what it may be referring to.

They “should” nothing. Double precision arithmetic will round the mantissa to 53 bits. The numbers involved will be rounded in ways that are hard to predict, and then all the information about the rounding is lost.
Sometimes two numbers that should be mathematically equal but were calculated in different ways are rounded the same way, sometimes they are not. Hard to predict. So sometimes the rounded numbers are the same, sometimes they are not.
